# ros tuetlebot3 launh file

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUEwT.png)

I am using ubuntu version 20.0.4

I have followed all the turtlebot simulation instruction [here](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#gazebo-simulation) but don't what is the issue I also check my bashrc file all the path are correct. Can anyone help me

Update by bashrc file

Run the turtlebot launch file

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance. Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You're running 20.04, which means your ROS version will be Noetic. However the tutorial you're referencing is written for Kinetic; which means you're installing a package for the wrong version.

You can either repeat the install instructions with: `git clone -b noetic-devel https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations.git`. Or `cd` into the cloned package and checkout the right branch via: `git checkout noetic-devel`.

Note that you'll most likely need to clean your workspace as it will not have built right.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir, I have check my noetic package and the turtlebot3 package are missing so i install those files and now it work properly

Comment: @NabajyotiDeori nice, glad to help. If you think this answer was sufficient feel free to mark it as accepted since it might helper others in the future.